# What town or towns will Aela not complain in with children?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Ok so I was able to marry Aela and get her as a companion. I did a little research and found out that if she gets a child or children, then she will complain about living in Whiterun, Riften and out of towns if the DLC is owned. For whiterun she says the house is too small for you, her and the children. For Riften she complains that the kid(s) will grow up to be thieves. Living outside of town she complains about the kids' safety and about the wolves and bears. (Despite the fact that we are both werewolves so the kids should be more than safe in the wild but whatever). Is there any town or towns that she won't complain about if she were to have children there?

Comment: How does the two of you being werewolves ensure your children's safety?

Comment: Would you mess with a child whose parents can turn themselves into werewolves at any given moment? 'Cause I definitely won't.

Comment: "Living outside of town she complains about the kids' safety and about the wolves and bears." Make sure you inform all the wolves and bears. Also, if the townsfolk knew you were werewolves they would show up with pitchforks and probably try to kill your children.

Answer (score 7):

Ok so I just did a little experiment. Used up the past 12 hours of my life to find out this information so I hope everyone finds it helpful. In whiterun Aela will complain that the house is too small for her and the children and you. In Riften she fears that the kids will become thieves (even if you are the guildmaster for the thieves guild but whatever). In Markarth she fears that the children will easily get hurt or wind up in the mines. In windhelm she claims the streets are crawling with filth and unsafe for the kids. In the heartfire home she gets mad at the dragonborn for moving them into the wilderness to get attacked by wolves, bears and giant spiders (AELA YOU ARE A FREAKING WEREWOLF WHY ARE A FEW PESTS SUCH A BIG DEAL FOR YOU?!). Solitude however she is completely fine with.

Comment: So she complains in all of the Hearthfire homes? Also, +1 for your 12-hour quest for answers.

Comment: Yea she does. It gets a little old for a while.

Comment: I do not regret it though. Found some pretty cool stuff and I got the nightingale armor, blade and bow. Totally worth it. I now look like a jet black scorpion from mortal combat. Lol

Answer (score 3):

Try to do it with safe homes like in Solitude. That house seems like nothing will both Alea. The house in Markarth also seems fine, though it might not be safe (because of elevation).

(Next time, don't have Alea as a spouse in the DLC, for she always complains, other spouses won't complain)

Comment: Did you try these houses? Did she complain?

Comment: I only have whiterun right now. I'm in the thieves guild and the companions if that helps any.

Comment: @ChronosMyth the thieves' guild doesn't seem to affect anything. You do have to be a Compainion to have Alea though.